# Blurry results on EPS/PDF import

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, inkscape

To the left is the image as generated by gnuplot (Gnuplot, with tex/pdf output, merged into a file, pdflatex, then cropped, then converted to EPS with `pdftops -eps`). To the right is the result of an import in Inkscape.

Whatever I do, the result comes blurry like on the right. 
Similar problems occur when I upload the image to a journal website (PLOS).

I tried importing from EPS, PDF and the result is always the same. 
Is there a way to keep the vector format and get rid of the blurriness?

[image: Problem example]

I run the latest version of inkscape.

Comment: Inherent blurriness would only appear if the image got rasterized -- and then you'd be able to zoom in and see blurry pixels. Are you sure this is not just an artifact of how Inkscape renders text at that size? (I'd be more worried on the Symbol angled brackets that disappeared.)

Comment: Well, the colormap is *not* text, so there's bound to be something else causing the problem. As for the missing symbol, it's merely because I did not have the proper font installed.

Comment: That question and answer at least explain what's happening.

Comment: If you generated the figure using `pm3d` then the color patches are not pixels, but polygons. The other way to plot this kind of map is using the `with image` style, which creates pixels. If you are using one way, then try the other method and see if that helps you.

Comment: @mlk Terrific search skills here! Thank you very much.

@Miguel I indeed used `with image`, so that would explain the potential for disastrous interpolation.

Comment: You must only keep in mind, that `pm3d` works differently: each data point is one corner of a rectangle, so you get only N-1 "pixel". And the color may be an interpolation of the four corner points. For your pixel size that could matter.